# Is the ball compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ of the continuous functions $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb R$, with $d_\infty(f,g)= \max_{x\in [0,1]} \lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert$.

Is the unit ball $\bar B _1 (0)$ compact, where $0$ is the zero constant function?

I just do not understand this question. The unit ball is closed because it is the closure of the ball, I assume, so I need to show boundedness. Can someone please help me understand the question and give me a hint? Also, how can one construct ball around a function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compact $\not\Leftrightarrow$ (closed and bounded) in general.

Comment: Since your metric space is not some $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed and boundedness will not suffice for compactness. I would suggest looking at different characterizations of compactness. In particular, for a metric space compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. Look there for a counterexample.

Comment: As for the question on "how can one construct ball around a function?": you have a metric between any two (continuous) functions on $[0,1]$, so by definition a closed unit ball around the $0$ function consists of exactly all continuous functions that are at distance at most $1$ from the zero function, for that metric.

Comment: You need absolute values in the definition of $d_\infty.$

Comment: A distance is positive, thus this is $max|f(x)-g(x)|$ I guess.

Comment: I did not know how to type that

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton \lvert and \rvert. I did it in your question.

Comment: @ClementC.thanks a lot

Comment: If I don't go wrong a normed space has a compact ball iff it is finite dimensional. Again if I don't go wrong $sin(nx)$, $cos(nx)$ should be linearly indipendent so this is not finite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. [Heine–Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) shows closed and bounded implies compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but in general it's not true.

For your question, [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) told us a unit ball is compact iff the normed vector space is finite dimensional.

If you want to use sequential compact to draw a contradiction, consider $f_n(t)=t^n$, $0\le t\le 1$. Then $\{f_n\} \subset \overline{B(0,1)}$ , but no subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges in $C[0,1]$ (with the sup norm).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Why is there not any subsequence of $f_n$ with the sup norm? I do not understand it

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton Hint: convergent in sup norm implies convergent pointwisely. Also a sequence of continuous functions convergent in sup norm implies the limit function is continuous. Can you find the pointwise limit function and draw a contradiction?

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton If there is a subsequence $(f_{n_j})_j$ that converges to some $f$, then $f$ is continuous since the closed ball is... closed. Now, what is $f(1)$? But what must be $f(t)$ for any $0\leq t< 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find a sequence in $\bar B_1(0)$ that has no subsequence converging in $C[0,1], d_\infty.$